# regular expression global pattern matching

Tags: php, regex

I do not repeat units in series (eg, 4, 6.5, 8, and 12 cm), except repeat % after each number
the series can be of any length,hence i want regex pattern to be global.
I have attached my sample program.

```
<?php
$match = '4 CM,6.5 CM';

$replacement='$1$2$3';
$replac = preg_replace('/(,?\d+\s?\W?)\w+?(,?\d+\s?\W?)(\w+)?/',
                   $replacement,
                   $match);
echo $replac;
?>
```

input:

```
4 CM,6.5 CM
```

output:

```
4 ,6.5 CM
```

Expected result:

input:

```
4 cm,6.5 cm,8 cm,9 cm and 10 cm  //the series can be of any length
```

output:

```
4,6.5,8,9 and 10 cm   //units at the end
```

help me out to make my regex as a global one.So that it can check for any number of series.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. Just remove all `cm` from the string, except for the last one.

```
$str = '4 cm,6.5 cm,8 cm,9 cm and 10 cm';
$out = preg_replace('/ cm(?!$)/i', '', $str);
```

Outputs: `4,6.5,8,9 and 10 cm`

Regex explained:

```
/ cm(?!$)/i
 \ /\   / ^
  |  \ /  |
  |   |   `-- Case insensitive
  |   `------ Negative lookahead, do not match if end of string
  `---------- Match " cm" literally
```

### [See it run](http://glot.io/php/441557d6d5f18e38f1bacd398c1bb3ef)

For a more general approach (capture any unit):

```
 / [^,]+(?=,| and )/i
  \    /\ /\     /  ^
   \  /  |  \   /   |
    \/   |   \ /    `-- Case insensitive
    |    |    `-------- Literal "," or " and "
    |    `------------- Positive lookahead, require following pattern
    `------------------ Capture until first comma (+ means 1 or more)
```

### [See it run](http://glot.io/php/441557d6d5f18e38f1bacd398c342d0e)

Comment: made things simple thanks.

Comment: can global regex pattern can be given for this situation???

Comment: Is there a way to replace cm in regex patten to variable which should capture any unit??

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '4 cm,6.5 cm,8 cm,9 cm and 10 cm';
$exploded = explode(' and ', $a);
```

$exploded[0] is "4 cm,6.5 cm,8 cm,9 cm"

$exploded[1] is "10 cm"

now lets remove " cm"

```
$beforeAnd = preg_replace('/ cm/', '', $exploded[0]);
```

$beforeAnd is "4,6.5,8,9"

```
$afterAnd = $exploded[1];
```

$afterAnd is "10 cm"

```
$result =  $beforeAnd . ' and ' . $afterAnd;
```

"4 cm,6.5 cm,8 cm,9 cm" + " and " + "10 cm"